# Consulta sql sobre una relación

Tags: mysql, select

Estaba intentado crear una consulta pero me es muy difícil, primero muestro la estructura y una parte de los datos de la tabla en cuestión.

```
mysql> desc rel_cat_videos;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| video | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cat   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM rel_cat_videos LIMIT 20;
+----+-------+-----+
| id | video | cat |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 |     1 |   5 |
|  2 |     1 |  73 |
|  3 |     1 |   2 |
|  4 |     1 |  15 |
|  5 |     2 |   5 |
|  6 |     2 |  69 |
|  7 |     2 |  78 |
|  8 |     2 |  80 |
|  9 |     3 |   5 |
| 10 |     3 |  36 |
| 11 |     3 |  38 |
| 12 |     3 |   6 |
| 13 |     3 |  34 |
| 14 |     3 |   3 |
| 15 |     4 |  74 |
| 16 |     4 |  87 |
| 17 |     4 |  29 |
| 18 |     4 |   9 |
| 19 |     5 |  56 |
| 20 |     5 |   2 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Lo que intento conseguir es que me devuelva un video por cada categoría ("cat") pero a la vez que no se repita ningún video

Comment: Hola @Cristían, ¿podrías ser más específico o poner un ejemplo de como esperas obtener el resultado? Ya que, así como mencionas que necesitas, me parece que no es posible, pues así como están los registros el resultado sí repetirá los videos pero en diferente categoría.

Comment: pongo un ejemplo, pongámonos en que hay 15 categorías , lo único que quiero obtener es 15 ids de 'video' con su correspondiente 'cat' y que en el resultado no aparezca repetido ninguna fila para la columna 'video'

Comment: Mmm... Podrías obtener los resultados usando un `select` y `group by` para agrupar por categorías. De esa forma me parece que tendrías el resultado deseado, solo toma en cuenta que, si hay más de un video (diferente) por categoría, aparecerá solamente el primero (el de id más bajo).

Comment: No sale el resultado esperado , pero de entre todo lo que he hecho me quedo con lo tuyo @IsidroSerranoPineda